# ArcGIS: h {name: "esri.layers.graphics.QueryEngine", message: "Unsupported query", details: undefined} when load data with api request

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm facing issue with Feature layer. When plot map with local data. But when I'm using hosted data in feature layer then Drawing feature is working fine and query on drawing data is also working perfectly.

But when I'm using my local system data using api request then draw objects on map is working fine but query filtering is not working on feature layer data. Below is the example code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.8/esri/css/main.css">

<style>
    #viewDiv {
        height: 100%;
    }
    .popUpMapView {
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #A8A8A8;
    }
    #drawActions {
        padding: 0 5px;
        background: #eee;
        border-left: 1px solid #999;
        border-right: 1px solid #999;
    }
    #drawActions ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #drawActions ul li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #drawActions ul li .esri-widget--button {
        background: #eee;
    }
    #drawActions ul li .esri-widget--button:hover {
        background: #fff;
    }
    .esri-ui-top-left .esri-component {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-top: solid 1px rgba(50,50,50,0.25);
    }
    .esri-popup.esri-widget {
      max-height: 100%;
    }

    .esri-view-width-xlarge .esri-popup__main-container {
      width: 580px;
    }

    .esri-view-height-less-than-medium .esri-popup__main-container {
      max-height: 500px;
    }

    .esri-view-height-small .esri-ui-corner .esri-component .esri-expand__content,
    .esri-view-width-greater-than-xsmall .esri-expand--auto .esri-expand__content {
        margin-left: 0;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .esri-widget--button {
        outline: 0;
    }
    .esri-legend__layer-body {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .color-selection-item-container {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .item-selected .color-selection-item-container {
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
    .item-selected .color-selection-item-container.active {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .item-selected .color-selection-item-container.active .esri-legend__layer-cell--info {
        color: #000;
    }
</style>


<script>
    var dojoConfig = {
        has: {
            "esri-featurelayer-webgl": 1
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.8/"></script>
<script>
    let highlight;
    let highlightFields = [];
    let povLayer;
    let plantTypeFilterObj = [];
    require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/WebMap",
        "esri/widgets/Sketch/SketchViewModel",
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Home",
        "esri/widgets/Legend",
        "esri/widgets/Expand",
        "esri/geometry/Point",
        "esri/config",
        "esri/request",
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(
        Map, MapView, WebMap, SketchViewModel, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, FeatureLayer, Home, Legend, Expand, Point, erisConfig, Request
    ) {

        const tempGraphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

        var map = new Map({
            basemap: "dark-gray",
            layers: [tempGraphicsLayer]
        });

        const view = new MapView({
            map: map,
            container: "viewDiv",
            center: [-91.891111, 42.477778],
            zoom: 4,
            highlightOptions: {
              color: "black",
              haloOpacity: 0,
              fillOpacity: 0.45
            },
        });

        let highlightHandle = null;

        view.when(function() {

                getData()
                    .then(createGraphics)
                    .then(createLayer)
                    .catch(errback);
        });

        function getData() {
            let url = "http://localhost/arcgis/points-listing";
            return Request(url, {
                responseType: "json"
            });
        }

        function createGraphics(response) {
            let items = response.data.data;
            let geojson = items.map(function(item, i) {
                return {
                    geometry: new Point({
                        x: item.lng,
                        y: item.lat
                    }),
                    attributes: {
                        ObjectID:           item.plant_id,
                        name:               item.name,
                        address:            item.street_address,
                        city:               item.city,
                        state_code:         item.state_code,
                        zip:                item.zip,
                        county:             item.county,
                        lng:                item.lng,
                        lat:                item.lat,
                        nameplate_capacity: item.nameplate_capacity,
                        plant_type:         item.plant_type
                    }
                };
            });

            return geojson;
        }

        function createLayer(graphics) {

            let layer = new FeatureLayer({
                source: graphics,

                fields: getFields(), 
                objectIdField: "ObjectID",
                renderer: getRender(),
                geometryType: "point",
                popupTemplate: getTemplate(),
                elevationInfo: {
                    mode: "on-the-ground"
                }
            });

            var legend = new Legend({
                view: view,
                layerInfos: [{
                    layer: layer,
                    title: "Plants detail"
                }]
            });
            view.ui.add(legend, "top-right");
            map.add(layer);

            view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function(layerView) {
                sketchGraphics(layerView);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    hideShowPointsOnPlantTypeBasis();
                    colorSelectionClick();
                }, 1000);
            });
            return layer;
        }

        function hideShowPointsOnPlantTypeBasis()
        {
            let legendContainer = document.getElementsByClassName("esri-legend__layer-table--size-ramp")[0];
            legendContainer.className += " color-section";
            let legendInfoItem = legendContainer.getElementsByClassName("esri-legend__layer-cell--info");


            for (let i = 0; i < legendInfoItem.length; i++) {

                let element = legendInfoItem[i];
                let text = element.innerHTML;
                let value = (text.toUpperCase()).replace(" ", "_");

                checkbox = document.createElement("input");
                checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                checkbox.setAttribute("class", "plant-type-filtering-checkbox");
                checkbox.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
                checkbox.setAttribute("value", value);

                element.parentNode.classList.add("color-selection-item-container");
                element.parentNode.insertBefore(checkbox, element.parentNode.firstChild);

            }
        }

        function colorSelectionClick() {
            $('.esri-expand__content').on('click', '.color-selection-item-container', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                let $this = $(this);
                let $input = $this.find('input.plant-type-filtering-checkbox');
                let selectedVal = $input.val();

                if(!$input.is(':checked')) {
                    plantTypeFilterObj.push(selectedVal);
                    $input.prop('checked', true);
                    $this.addClass('active');

                } else {
                    $this.removeClass('active');
                    plantTypeFilterObj = plantTypeFilterObj.filter(function(value, index, arr){
                        return value != selectedVal;
                    });
                    $input.prop('checked', false);
                }

                let layerViews = view.layerViews;
                if(plantTypeFilterObj.length > 0) {
                    viewLayer.layer.definitionExpression = "nameplate_capacity > 0 AND plant_type IN ('" + plantTypeFilterObj.join("','") + "')";
                } else {
                    viewLayer.layer.definitionExpression = '';
                }

                let selectedCount = $('.esri-expand__content').find('.color-selection-item-container.active').length;
                if(selectedCount > 0) {
                    $('.esri-expand__content').addClass('item-selected');
                } else {
                    $('.esri-expand__content').removeClass('item-selected');
                }
            });
        }

        function sketchGraphics(layer) {

            viewLayer = layer;

            // create a new sketch view model
            const sketchViewModel = new SketchViewModel({
                view: view,
                layer: tempGraphicsLayer,
                pointSymbol: {
                    type: "simple-marker", // autocasts as new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
                    style: "square",
                    size: "16px"
                }
            });


            setUpClickHandler(view);
            sketchViewModel.on("create", createGraphic);
            sketchViewModel.on("create-complete", addGraphic);

            // Listen the sketchViewModel's update-complete and update-cancel events
            sketchViewModel.on("update-complete", updateGraphic);
            sketchViewModel.on("update-cancel", updateGraphic);


            var drawCircleButton = document.getElementById("circleButton");
            var drawRectangleButton = document.getElementById("rectangleButton");
            var drawPolygonButton = document.getElementById("polygonButton");

            drawCircleButton.onclick = function() {
              resetSketchView();
              sketchViewModel.create("circle");

              setActiveButton(this);
            };

            drawRectangleButton.onclick = function() {
              resetSketchView();
              sketchViewModel.create("rectangle");

              setActiveButton(this);
            };

            drawPolygonButton.onclick = function() {
                resetSketchView();

                sketchViewModel.create("polygon");
                setActiveButton(this);
            };

            view.on('click', function(event) {
                resetSketchView();
            });

            // reset all the changes from map on btn click.
            document.getElementById("resetBtn").onclick = function() {
                resetSketchView();
            };

            function addGraphic(event) {
                const graphic = new Graphic({
                    geometry: event.geometry,
                    symbol: sketchViewModel.graphic.symbol
                });
                tempGraphicsLayer.add(graphic);
                selectFeatures(event.geometry);
            }

            function createGraphic(event) {
                resetHideShowPoints();
            }

            function updateGraphic(event) {
              event.graphic.geometry = event.geometry;
              tempGraphicsLayer.add(event.graphic);

              editGraphic = null;
            }

            function setActiveButton(selectedButton) {

                view.focus();
                var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
                for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                    elements[i].classList.remove("active");
                }
                if (selectedButton) {
                    selectedButton.classList.add("active");
                }
            }

            function resetSketchView() {
                sketchViewModel.reset();
                tempGraphicsLayer.removeAll();

                // remove existing highlighted features
                if (highlight) {
                    highlight.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        function selectFeatures(geometry) {

            view.graphics.removeAll();
            if (viewLayer) {

                let query = {};
                query.returnGeometry = true;
                query.outFields = ["*"];

                viewLayer.queryFeatures(query).then(function(results) {

                    const graphics = results.features;

                    if (graphics.length > 0) {

                        // remove existing highlighted features
                        if (highlight) {
                            highlight.remove();
                        }

                        highlight = viewLayer.highlight(graphics);
                    }
                })
                .catch(errback);
            }
        }

        function removeUnSelectedPoints(viewLayer, graphics)
        {
            graphics.forEach(item => {
                highlightFields.push(item.attributes.FID);
            });

            setTimeout(function() {
                viewLayer.layer.definitionExpression = "FID IN (" + highlightFields.join(",") + ")";
            }, 1000);
        }

        function resetHideShowPoints() {

            if(highlightFields.length > 0) {
                highlightFields = [];
                viewLayer.layer.definitionExpression = "";
                console.log('reset', highlightFields);
            }
        }

        function errback(error) {
            console.error(error);
        }

        function setUpClickHandler(mapview) {
            mapview.on("click", function(event) {

                event.stopPropagation();
                streetView(view, event)

                mapview.hitTest(event).then(function(response) {
                    var results = response.results;
                });
            });
        }

        function streetView(mainMapView, event) {

            // Make sure that there is a valid latitude/longitude
            if (event && event.mapPoint) {

                // Create lat/lon vars to display in popup title
                var lat = Math.round(event.mapPoint.latitude * 1000) / 1000;
                var lon = Math.round(event.mapPoint.longitude * 1000) / 1000;

                mainMapView.popup.open({
                    // Set the popup's title to the coordinates of the location
                    title: "Map view coordinates: [" + lon + ", " + lat + "]",
                    location: event.mapPoint, // Set the location of the popup to the clicked location
                    content: innerMapPopUp(
                        mainMapView,
                        mainMapView.center,
                        mainMapView.scale
                    )
                });
            } else {
                mainMapView.popup.open({
                    // Set the popup's title to the coordinates of the location
                    title: "Invalid point location",
                    location: event.mapPoint, // Set the location of the popup to the clicked location
                    content: "Please click on a valid location."
                });
            }
        }

        function innerMapPopUp(mainMapView, center, scale) {
            var popupDiv = document.createElement("div");
            popupDiv.classList.add("popUpMapView");

            var popupView = new MapView({
                container: popupDiv,
                map: new Map({
                    basemap: "topo"
                }),
                center: center,
                zoom: 8,
                ui: {
                    components: []
                }
            });
            console.log(popupView);
            // Return a dom node
            return popupView.container;
        }

        function getFields() {
            var fields = [
                {
                    name: "ObjectID",
                    alias: "ObjectID",
                    type: "oid"
                }, {
                    name: "name",
                    alias: "name",
                    type: "string"
                }, {
                    name: "address",
                    alias: "address",
                    type: "string"
                }, {
                    name: "city",
                    alias: "city",
                    type: "string"
                }, {
                    name: "state_code",
                    alias: "state_code",
                    type: "string"
                }, {
                    name: "zip",
                    alias: "zip",
                    type: "string"
                }, {
                    name: "county",
                    alias: "county",
                    type: "string"
                }, {
                    name: "plant_type",
                    alias: "plant_type",
                    type: "string"
                }, {
                    name: "nameplate_capacity",
                    alias: "nameplate_capacity",
                    type: "double"
                }
            ];
            return fields;
        }
        function getTemplate() {
            // Set up popup template for the layer
            var pTemplate = {
                title: "{name}",
                content: [{
                    type: "fields",
                    fieldInfos: [
                        {
                            fieldName: "street_address",
                            label: "Address",
                            visible: true
                        }, 
                        {
                            fieldName: "city",
                            label: "City",
                            visible: true
                        }, 
                        {
                            fieldName: "state_code",
                            label: "State Code",
                            visible: true
                        }, 
                        {
                            fieldName: "zip",
                            label: "Zip",
                            visible: true
                        },
                        {
                            fieldName: "county",
                            label: "County",
                            visible: true
                        },
                        {
                            fieldName: "plant_type",
                            label: "Plant Type",
                            visible: true
                        },
                        {
                            fieldName: "latitude",
                            label: "Latitude",
                            visible: true
                        },
                        {
                            fieldName: "longitude",
                            label: "Longitude",
                            visible: true
                        },
                        {
                            fieldName: "nameplate_capacity",
                            label: "Capacity (MW)",
                            visible: true
                        }
                    ]
                }]
            };
            return pTemplate;
        }

        function getRender() {

            var renderer = {
                type: "unique-value", // autocasts as new SimpleRenderer()
                // Define a default marker symbol with a small outline
                symbol: {
                  type: "simple-marker", // autocasts as new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
                  color: "#FFD733"
                },
                defaultLabel: "Other",
                field: "plant_type",
                label: "Plant Type",

                uniqueValueInfos: [
                    {
                        value: "HYDRO",
                        symbol: {
                            type: "simple-marker",
                            color: "hsla(345,80%, 65%, 1)"
                        },
                        label: "Hydro"
                    },
                    {
                        value: "NATURAL_GAS",
                        symbol: {
                            type: "simple-marker",
                            color: "hsla(213,80%, 65%, 1)"
                        },
                        label: "Natural Gas"
                    },
                    {
                        value: "BIOMASS",
                        symbol: {
                            type: "simple-marker",
                            color: "hsla(195,80%, 65%, 1)"
                        },
                        label: "Biomass"
                    },
                    {
                        value: "COAL",
                        symbol: {
                            type: "simple-marker",
                            color: "hsla(336,80%, 65%, 1)"
                        },
                        label: "Coal"
                    },
                    {
                        value: "NUCLEAR",
                        symbol: {
                            type: "simple-marker",
                            color: "hsla(224,80%, 65%, 1)"
                        },
                        label: "Nuclear"
                    },
                    {
                        value: "PETROLIUM",
                        symbol: {
                            type: "simple-marker",
                            color: "hsla(264,80%, 65%, 1)"
                        },
                        label: "Petrolium"
                    },
                    {
                        value: "SOLAR",
                        symbol: {
                            type: "simple-marker",
                            color: "hsla(287,80%, 65%, 1)"
                        },
                        label: "Solar"
                    },
                    {
                        value: "WIND",
                        symbol: {
                            type: "simple-marker",
                            color: "hsla(344,80%, 65%, 1)"
                        },
                        label: "Wind"
                    }
                ],
                visualVariables: [
                    {
                        type: "size",
                        field: "nameplate_capacity",
                        valueUnit: "unknown",
                        legendOptions: {
                              title: "Nameplate Capacity (MW)"
                        },
                        stops: [
                        {
                          value: 500,
                          size: 10,
                          label: "<500"
                        },
                        {
                          value: 2000,
                          size: 15,
                          label: "1000"
                        },
                        {
                          value: 3000,
                          size: 20,
                          label: "4000"
                        },
                        {
                          value: 5000,
                          size: 35,
                          label: "< 10000"
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            };

            return renderer;
        }

        // Set up a home button for resetting the viewpoint to the intial extent
        var homeBtn = new Home({
            view: view
        }, "homeDiv");

        // Instructions expand widget
        const drawIcons = document.getElementById("drawActions");
        instructionsExpand = new Expand({
          expandIconClass: "esri-icon-expand",
          expandTooltip: "Draw Actions",
          expanded: false,
          view: view,
          iconNumber: 4,
          content: drawIcons
        });

        view.ui.add(homeBtn, "top-left");
        view.ui.add(instructionsExpand, "top-left");

        // hide the instructions expand widget when the view becomes focused
        view.watch("focused", function(newValue, oldValue, property, object) {
          if (newValue) {
            instructionsExpand.expanded = false;
          }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And below is the screen-shot what issue I'm getting.
[image]

I spend my too much time to research on that. But unfortunately I'm not finding any way how to resolve this issue.
Please give a clue what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not setting up the query correctly. You have:

```
let query = {};
query.returnGeometry = true;
query.outFields = ["*"];
viewLayer.queryFeatures(query)
```

You need to use the [featureLayer's `createQuery`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-FeatureLayer.html#createQuery) method to create a query object:

```
let query = layer.createQuery();
query.returnGeometry = true;
query.outFields = ["*"];
viewLayer.queryFeatures(query)
```

Also, WebGL rendering is only supported for layers hosted on ArcGIS Online, or on ArcGIS Server 10.6.1 so highlight and other functionality will not work on layers that do not meet these requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that solution is not working. getting same  issue.